# Postfix bounces and rejects some of non existing emails for same domain

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

Postfix serves for my virtual domains and works fine. 
But for one of my domains: 
 - it bounces mails targeted at mail@domain.tld 
 - it rejects mails targeted at nonexisting@domain.tld

problem is, mail@domain.tld does not exist either.

here is my [postconf](http://dpaste.com/hold/193740/)

why does it bounce mail@domain.tld, and reject other non existing mails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing a bounce message. Check the bounce error message and also look into your mail log (frequently /var/log/mail.log or maillog) to get more information about why it is bouncing.

Edit: OP solved problem by removing unix:passwd.byname from local_recipient_maps in the main.cf Postfix configuration file.

Comment: argh! seems that postfix accepts the mails for systemuser@virtualdomain.tld, then finds out that no systemuser  mailbox exists for virtualdomain.tld and bounces..
i've tried it with system(linux) users such as mail, news, games @virtualdomain.tlds i'm hosting and all bounced. but bogus account names such as foo, bar etc. are rejected.

Comment: well, you can remove the system users as valid users from your postfix configuration, if no local (/etc/passwd) users are meant to get mail.

i don't know off the top of my head how to remove the configuration, but it shouldn't be hard. i presume you're using virtual users hosted in a database or something?

Comment: yep removing  unix:passwd.byname from local_recipient_maps solved my problem, thanks cpbills.